# Better way to parse JSON for navigation

Tags: php, json

I am working on creating a navigation from JSON, with both a link for the top level and sub-levels. I intend this to be reusable for different depths of multidimensional JSON file, blog nav, pages, etc...

I feel like my code is a bit convoluted and would love some help simplifying this.

```
function generate_navigation($document,$navigation){
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/json/navigation.json'),true);
$parent = $document->createElement('nav');
$i = 0;
function build_segment($document,$node,$data,$name,$i){
    foreach($data as $key => $link){
        if(!is_array($link)){
            $a = $document->createElement('a');
            $a->setAttribute('href',$link);
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $link_title = $key;
            } else {
                $link_title = $name;
                $node->setAttribute('class','has-children');
            }
            $a->appendChild($document->createTextNode($link_title));
            $node->appendChild($a);
        } else {
            $nav[$i] = $document->createElement('nav');
            $node->appendChild($nav[$i]);
            build_segment($document,$nav[$i],$link,$key,$i);
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
build_segment($document,$parent,$json[$navigation],null,$i);
return $parent;
}
```

and the JSON

```
{
"Primary":
    {
        "Home": "/",
        "Blog": "/posts/",
        "Events": "/events/",
        "Places": [
            "/places/",
            {
            "Counties": "/places/counties/",
            "Municipalities": "/places/municipalities/"
            }
        ],
        "Activities": [
            "/activities/",
            {
            "Golf": "/activities/golf/",
            "Disk Golf": "/activities/disc-golf/",
            "Fishing": "/activities/fishing/"
            }
        ],
        "Resources": [
            "/resources/",
            {
            "Public": "/resources/public/",
            "Families": "/resources/families/",
            "Business": "/resources/business/",
            "Hospitals": "/resources/hospitals/"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: well I can tell you the second you call `generate_navigation` twice it's going to blow up, please see > http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de5e492a8d6ed9c6b8d0070f8f027f76253d3309

Comment: Because you nested the definition of `build_segment` so once you call the outer function the second time, that function has been previously defined (in the first call) and the second call will die, basically.  But SO is not really code review.

Comment: Actually, this is working. But as you said, it is flawed. I'm back at the keyboard and reviewing it but my brain hurts trying to visualize the recursive action to simplify it. Would love to make this better for production and share it on GitHub.

Comment: You can change it to a closure, or define the function separately, the second being the better choice.  However I have written a JSON lexer/parser, not for this case but it may give you some ideas.  It works without json_decode.  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/JasonDecoder.php